# How to show that greatest common factor of $(m+n$ and $ m-n)\in\mathbb{N}$ is equal to $1$ or $2$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

We have $m,n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $gcd(m,n) = 1.$

How to prove that $gcd(m+n,m-n) = 1$ or $2$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: $\gcd(m+n,m-n) \mid \gcd\big((m+n)+(m-n), (m+n)-(m-n)\big)=\gcd(2m,2n)\,$.

Comment: It would be more helpful if You could write solution whit steps.

Comment: @ZvnokyBrown For any integers $u,v\,$, $d=\gcd(u,v) \mid u$ and $d \mid v\,$ by the definition of $\gcd\,$. It follows that $d \mid u+v$ and $d \mid u-v\,$, therefore $d \mid \gcd(u+v, u-v)\,$. The above is just using this property for $u=m+n$ and $v=m-n\,$.